# C++ WTL: Deriving from CListBox

Tags: c++, wtl

I'm trying to create a custom CListBox derived class. I am having trouble figuring out how to set up the message map stuff properly. This is the current code I am using:

```
template <class T>
class CHScrollListBoxT : public CWindowImpl<CHScrollListBoxT<T> , CListBox>
{
public:
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CHScrollListBoxT< T >)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(LB_ADDSTRING, OnAddString)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(LB_INSERTSTRING, OnInsertString)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(LB_DELETESTRING, OnDeleteString)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(LB_DIR, OnDir)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(LB_RESETCONTENT, OnResetContent)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    ...
```

The problem I am having is how to route the rest of the window messages back to the base CListBox class (in other words, do default processing for any window messages I do not specify in the message map). I do not want to have to override every applicable message handler for a CListBox. I tried:

```
CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CWindowImpl<CHScrollListBoxT<T>, CListBox>
```

But it does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the compiler error, but supposedly the problem is that you are providing macro argument with embedded spaces and commas. You can work it around this way:

```
typedef CWindowImpl<CHScrollListBoxT<T>, CListBox> CBaseWindow;
CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CBaseWindow)
```